# Creating a JFrame you can click through on mac os

Tags: java, macos, jframe, graphics2d

I have come across multiple threads of similar questions. However, they all imply that to achieve a JFrame that can be clicked through, you need to use code native to the system you are using and many answers that are given are for the windows operating system.

This is what my main looks like:

```
    JCanvas can = new JCanvas();

    DrawFrame df = new DrawFrame("Draw", can);
    Dimension screenSize = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    df.setSize((int)screenSize.getWidth(), (int)screenSize.getHeight());
    df.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    df.setUndecorated(true);
    df.setVisible(true);
```

I've achieved clicking through when I make my JFrame totally transparent, however that is not what I am trying to achieve. Also, JCanvas is just an image that I draw onto that is added to the JFrame.

If it is not possible to click through windows in java. Which language would be more suitable for this?

ps. I am trying to create a screen marker application